# php FTP Wrapper writes empty files (0 Byte), FTP Extension doesn't

Tags: php, ftp

On a server with PHP 5.2.17 running, using any function which makes use of the built in ftp wrapper to upload a file, creates an empty file on the server:

- `file_put_contents()` returns with the accurate number of bytes
- `copy()` also returns with true

Both create the file, but it's empty.

When trying with `ftp_put()` from the FTP extension, both in binary and ascii mode, it works well.

On my workstation with PHP 5.3.10 it somehow works also with the wrapper.

In code:

```
$source = '/tmp/testfile';
$target = 'ftp://user:pass@example.com/testfile';

copy($source, $target);
```

gives no error or warning, but leaves an empty file on the server.

```
$source = '/tmp/testfile';
$target = 'testfile';

$ftp = ftp_connect('example.com');
ftp_login($ftp, 'user', 'pass');
ftp_put($ftp, $target, $source, FTP_ASCII);
ftp_close($ftp);
```

works in every respect.

thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: You should provide code and debug output, we can't guess what you're doing exactly.

Comment: Also make sure the server you are working on is not full (disk quota maxed out), otherwise everything you upload will be created but is always empty [0 bytes].

Comment: Thx for your comments. @DexterHuinda ftp_put() works for me, so no duplicate, and server cannot be full.

Comment: So what doesn't work? Where is the sample code?

Comment: `file_put_contents()` and `copy()` create an empty file. Example: `file_put_contents('ftp://user:pass@example.com/file', 'Some content')`;

Comment: See also this if it answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600611/file-get-contents-creating-an-empty-file You should show a fragment of your code, from the part on how you read the file up to writing it. No way we can debug if you don't show any code.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried SSH2 libs? Some sample implementation below:

```
public function uploadSFTP($host_name, $port, $user, $publicSshKeyPath, $privateSshKeyPath, $remoteFile, $localFile, $fileOperation = 'w') 
{
    $ssh_conn = ssh2_connect($host_name, $port);

    if (ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($ssh_conn, $user, $publicSshKeyPath, $privateSshKeyPath)) 
    {
        $sftp_conn = ssh2_sftp($ssh_conn);
        $inputfileStream = @fopen('ssh2.sftp://' . $sftp_conn . $remoteFile, $fileOperation);

        try 
        {
            if (!$inputfileStream)
                throw new Exception('Could open remote file for writing: ' . $remoteFile);

            $localFileContents = @file_get_contents($localFile);

            if ($localFileContents === FALSE)
                throw new Exception('Could not open local file for reading :' . $localFile);

            if (@fwrite($inputfileStream, $localFileContents) === FALSE)
                throw new Exception('Could not SFTP file');
        } 
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {
            // Do something...
        }

        fclose($sftpInfileStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't answer the question. Using the normal ftp-extension already works.